# Hidden field doesn't POST along with file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following MVC form and controller to upload an image for merchandise with a given id. The id is null when this form is submitted to the controller for some reason. I checked in the rendered HTML and the correct ID is being rendered on the webpage.

The form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(new{id = ViewBag.id})){

<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="@ViewBag.Id"/>

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" />
}
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddImage(int merchandiseId, HttpPostedFileBase image)
<snip>
```

Why would submitting this form cause merchandiseId to be null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becouse you use wrong names. Change

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="@ViewBag.Id"/>
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="merchandiseId" id="id" value="@ViewBag.Id"/>
```

**or**

```
public ActionResult AddImage(int merchandiseId, HttpPostedFileBase image)
```

to

```
public ActionResult AddImage(int id, HttpPostedFileBase image)
```

Answer (score 1):

`merchandiseId` would be 0 (and not null) because there is no input on your form called `merchandiseId`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="merchandiseId" id="merchandiseId" value="@ViewBag.Id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Html.BeginForm` like below :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(new{merchandiseId = ViewBag.id}))
```

This will fix your problem.